# making TeX documents ragged left justified?

Tags: latex, tex, typesetting

How can I make my entire LaTeX document (using TeXShop in Mac OS X) left justified, in a "ragged left" mode?  I don't want to use blocks of \begin{flushleft} everywhere, I just want to declare somewhere in the document header that the whole document should be this way.  Right now everything is fully justified (like newspapers) by default.

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/ if you need to ask TeX questions.

Comment: belongs on tex.stackexchange.com?

Comment: TeX questions that have the programming nature are still on topic on Stack Overflow, though you may get a better response on the Stack Exchange site. *This* question is probably better on the specialist site.

Comment: Until the beta is over and the TeX site is up and running permanently, I don't think we should scare people off posting TeX related questions here. That said, friendly suggestions to try the beta site are still a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it globally:

```
\raggedright
```

See the `ragged2e` package to enable hyphenation in ragged prargraphs.

Comment: That doesn't work for me -- I get the error "There's no line to end"

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
\raggedleft
```